# Are string literals immutable?

Tags: rust, immutability, string-literals

I am reading the Rust book to learn Rust and currently learning about ownership. It mentions that:

> We’ve already seen string literals, where a string value is hardcoded
> into our program. String literals are convenient, but they aren’t
> suitable for every situation in which we may want to use text. One
> reason is that they’re immutable.

The code below runs without any problem. Here I changed the value of `a`, if immutable strings can be changed what’s the problem stated there?

```
fn main() {
   let mut a = "Hello";
   println!("{}", a);
   a = " World";
   println!("{}", a);
}
```

Comment: In your example, `a` is a mutable binding to an immutable slice.  You can change which immutable slice it is bound to (as you have done), but you still can't mutate the slices themselves.

Comment: For example `a.make_ascii_uppercase()` will fail.

Comment: Welcome to the difference between a value and a variable name. You can still re-assign a mutable variable name to a new value, even if those values are themselves immutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The executable binary produced by the rust compiler contains the string literals "Hello" and "World" in the read-only data section `rodata`.

```
$ cargo build --release
$ readelf -x .rodata target/release/demo | grep Hello
  0x0003c000 48656c6c 6f000000 0a576f72 6c640000 Hello....World..
```

Because these literals are placed in an immutable section, the operating system prohibits modifying them.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: &'static str = "Hello";
    println!("{}", a);

    unsafe { (a.as_ptr() as *mut u8).write(42) };
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

```
$ cargo run
Hello
Segmentation fault
```

However, the *variable* `a` is of type `&str`, so a pointer to a string slice, and it lives on the stack. Therefore, it is totally valid for `a` to first point to the address of "Hello", and then to the address of "World".

---

**EDIT**: Information about the `unsafe` block

We want to write something to the address where `a` points to, to show that it is indeed stored in a read-only section.

`a` is declared as `mut a: &str`, meaning the variable is mutable, but the data (string literal) is immutable (in contrast to `mut a: &mut str` ️).
Thus, the compiler prevents us from using [`a.as_mut_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_mut_ptr) to get a mutable (aka writable) pointer to the underlying bytes.

Instead, we have to do a little trick: Use [`a.as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_ptr) and cast the returned `const *u8` to a `mut *u8`. Finally, writing to a pointer requires an `unsafe` block, because you can violate Rust's memory safety, which can result in bad things happening, like the Segmentation Fault shown above.

Comment: Could you explain the `unsafe` line ?

Comment: @DevonDahon Edited the answer to include an explanation of the unsafe line